# Where should I call Interface in android?

Tags: java, android, interface, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to call the activity method from the adaptor class using interface.**And both the activity are independent i.e. class which is calling adapter and the class where the method is defined.**

Interface class

```
public interface AdapterCallback  {        
    int onMethodCallback();
}
```

Adapter class

```
public class SimpleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SimpleAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    String[] goals;
    Context context;
    private AdapterCallback mAdapterCallback;


    public  SimpleAdapter(Context context, String[] goals)
    {
        super();
        this.context=context;
        this.goals=goals;


    }

   /* public SimpleAdapter(Context context) {

        try {

        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException("Activity must implement AdapterCallback.");
        }

    }*/

    @Override
    public SimpleAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.simple_item,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final SimpleAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

      holder.textView.setText(goals[position]);

      holder.textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View view) {

              try {
                  mAdapterCallback = ((AdapterCallback) context);
                  int result=mAdapterCallback.onMethodCallback();
                  Toast.makeText(context,Integer.toString(result), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              } catch (ClassCastException exception) {
                  // do something
                  Log.i("In the catch","Yes");
              }




          }
      });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return  goals.length;
    }


    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        Button textView;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            textView=(Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);
        }
    }

}
```

Method is defined in the MainActivity.class

```
@Override
public int onMethodCallback() {
    // do something
    return 2;
}
```

**Problem:**
How should I call the interface function so that indirectly it will call the function defined in the MainActivity class.

I know I need to provide the context of the MainActivity as

```
mAdapterCallback = ((AdapterCallback) context);
```

but where should I put this code.

IF i put this code in the constructor then it will not get the MainActivity class context because adapter is calling from another class.

**EDIT:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterCallback {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int onMethodCallback() {
        // do something
        return 2;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    public int sampleFunction()
    {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Class which is calling the adaptor class

```
public class OtherClass extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter;
    String[]  action_name={"Swimming","Yoga","SWD","IFT","Follow Diet Plan", "Diagnostic Tests","Record Temperature","Record Blood Pressure"," Record Sugar Level","Record Weight"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.xtra);

        recyclerView=(RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recylerview);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


        simpleAdapter=new SimpleAdapter(this, action_name);

        recyclerView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the code of MainActivity?

Comment: Done @DeepakSachdeva

Comment: Check my posted solution.

Comment: Updated @DeepakSachdeva

Comment: @AnkurKhandelwal try my soln? Let me know If u have any issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have set the interface.Write a method like this in your adapter class

```
    AdapterCallback  adapterCallback ;
    public void setAdapterCallback(AdapterCallback adapterCallback){
      this.adapterCallback = adapterCallback
    }
```

Now impliment and initialize the interface where you actually requires the callback. In your case `MainActivity` Do like this

```
MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterCallback
```

now initialize your interface like this.

```
   SimpleAdapter adpter = new SimpleAdapter()   
   adpter.setAdapterCallback(this);       // very imp step
```

Now send the callback like this

```
 holder.textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View view) {
               if(adapterCallback  != null){
                  adapterCallback.onMethodCallback();  
              }
          }
      });
```

That's all you will get callback on your mainactivity..

**Edit**

I see you have your adapter set in another activity ..In that case you have to pass your interface object like this

```
AdapterCallback  adapterCallback = this;
Intent intent = new Intent(context, OtherClass.class);
intent.putExtra("interface", adapterCallback);
startActivity(intent);
```

And retreive it in OtherClass;

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
AdapterCallback   inter = (AdapterCallback) intent.getSerializableExtra("interface");
```

Also change interface to serializable .

```
public interface AdapterCallback  extends Serializable {
     int onMethodCallback();
}
```

And setInterface like this

```
  simpleAdapter.setAdapterCallback(inter);
```

If you jsut used a fragment instead of otherclass it would have been a lot easier..

**Edit**

If both activities are independent then you can write a gettter and setter for your interface in Application class. Set the interface from mainActivity and get the callback in your adater..
  write this in your **Application class**

```
AdapterCallback  adapterCallback;
public AdapterCallback getAdapterCallback() {
    return adapterCallback;
}

public void setAdapterCallback(AdapterCallback adapterCallback) {
    this.adapterCallback = adapterCallback;
}
```

Write this in your **Main**

```
((YourApplication)getApplication()). setAdapterCallback(this);
```

And use this method in your click

```
((YourApplication) getApplication()).getAdapterCallback().onMethodCallback();
```

Comment: Hey I have tried it but getting adapterCallback= null,  and I also add  the constructor public SimpleAdapter(Context context) {

        try {
            this.context=context;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException("Activity must implement AdapterCallback.");
        }

    }   for  SimpleAdapter adpter = new SimpleAdapter()

Comment: I think you are getting all wrong. calling method is like completely independent and there is no relation in between MainActivity and otherclass. If I set like this   startActivity(intent); then MainActivity always move to otherclass

Comment: @AnkurKhandelwal then why are you calling this  startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,OtherClass.class)); and where do you want the callback

Comment: this is just the dummy.. I can't put the actual code as this very long and will not serve the purpuse..

Comment: Is there any way without using  the fragment.

Comment: @AnkurKhandelwal Then you are misleading now.. From your code it's saying You want callback in MainActivity but you have initialized adapter from otherclass..so the callback is recieved at otherclss only..

Comment: @AnkurKhandelwal Where do you want your callback.. In mainactivity ?

Comment: Ok. I did't have intention of mislead you. sorry for that. I have updated my question. I thing callback term is creating confusion for  me. My sole purpose of asking this question is how will I call a method from an adapter which is declared in the outside class( means not in the adaptor calling class). @sunil

Comment: @AnkurKhandelwal Ok now the question make sense ..Please remove test() from your code ..It's misleading

Comment: @AnkurKhandelwal see edit .. You have to cast context to activty to get application in adapter like this   mActivity = (Activity) context. and use mActivity.getApplication()

Answer (score 0):

```
   public class SimpleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SimpleAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    String[] goals;
    Context context;
    private AdapterCallback mAdapterCallback;


    public  SimpleAdapter(Context context, String[] goals)
    {
        super();
        this.context=context;
        this.goals=goals;
    }

   /* public SimpleAdapter(Context context) {

        try {

        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException("Activity must implement AdapterCallback.");
        }

    }*/

    @Override
    public SimpleAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.simple_item,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final SimpleAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.textView.setText(goals[position]);

        holder.textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                try {
                    mAdapterCallback = ((AdapterCallback) context);
                    int result=mAdapterCallback.onMethodCallback();
                    Toast.makeText(context,Integer.toString(result), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } catch (ClassCastException exception) {
                    // do something
                    Log.i("In the catch","Yes");
                }
            }
        });

    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return  goals.length;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        Button textView;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView=(Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);
            //for entire cell
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            //or only for button
            textView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            /*
            If your want clicked position you can use bellow code
             */
            //int clicked_position = getAdapterPosition();
            mAdapterCallback.onMethodCallback(clicked_position,goals[clicked_position]);
        }
    }
}
```

this is the way we have to use interface in android recyclerview

**Edits**

change your interface like bellow

```
public interface AdapterCallback  {
    void onMethodCallback(int position,String value);
}
```

and on your OtherClass.class like bellow

```
    public class OtherClass extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterCallback{

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter;
    String[]  action_name={"Swimming","Yoga","SWD","IFT","Follow Diet Plan", "Diagnostic Tests","Record Temperature","Record Blood Pressure"," Record Sugar Level","Record Weight"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.xtra);

        recyclerView=(RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recylerview);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


        simpleAdapter=new SimpleAdapter(this, action_name);

        recyclerView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);

    }

    @Override
    public void onMethodCallback(int position, String value) {
        System.out.println(value+"    "+position);
        //start activity intent here , now you have position as well as selected value
    }
}
```

Comment: OP's issue means?

Comment: **Problem:** How should I call the interface function so that indirectly it will call the function defined in the MainActivity class.? read next 4 lines after this statement in the Original Post

Comment: just add " implements AdapterCallback " on your activity after AppCompactActivity or Activity

Comment: can you post your activity here?

Comment: Read the question there is no connection between MainActivity and the Adapter. That is the issue.

Comment: Where is your recyclerview in mainActivity?

Comment: that means if I click on any button then interface method will call?? If in future i have added the some condition like i>5 call func1 and i<5 call funct 2 and i==5 call funct3 then how will I tackle this problem.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zFh-ESQJF9k  look at this you will get to know how recyclerview is used in activity

Comment: is your app running now?

Comment: No. @JefriiyerS

Comment: watch the youtube link , then it will work for you, RecyclerView needs initialization on onCreate, simply adding to layout is not enough

Comment: now the edited answer will work for you, there is the change in adapter class as well

Answer (score 0):

If you have implemented interface **AdapterCallback** in MainActivity then call constructor of SimpleAdapter with including a new paramenter of AdapterCallback Object. Try with these change. It may helps you

```
String[] goals;
Context context;
private AdapterCallback mAdapterCallback;

public  SimpleAdapter(Context context, AdapterCallback adapterCallback, String[] goals){
        super();
        this.context=context;
        this.adapterCallback = adapterCallback;
        this.goals=goals;
    }
```

and remove this

```
mAdapterCallback = ((AdapterCallback) context);
```

Comment: The class from which I am calling the adapter is different then the class where I have defined the interface method definition.

Comment: Just for clarification so he needs to prepare the data and everything in MainActivity and in existing Activity?

Comment: please post code, where you are calling SimpleAdapter.

Comment: Suppose you have 2 Activity A and B, and B Activity has adapter. Then implement a interface in B activity and get data in implemented method of interface in B Activity, Then call finish(). After finish B activity you can move with data to onActivityResult() of Activity A. then you can use your data in A Activity. May be it solves your problem.

Comment: First I can't declare the function in activity B(adapter calling class). @DeepakSachdeva

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure just a work around try,

If u have an Util class create a method or Create a Util class and do

say

```
 private Context mContext;
    public void setContext(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    public Context getContext(){

        return mContext;
    }
```

Then

set the context in MainActivity

like

```
Util.setContext(MainActivity.this);
```

and in SimpleAdapter class use Util.getContext() and

```
Context context = Util.getContext();
 if(context != null && context instanceof MainActivity){
    mAdapterCallback = ((AdapterCallback) context);
    int result=mAdapterCallback.onMethodCallback();
 }
```